# Grails 2.3.x lib directory with customized plugins

Tags: grails

I'm not sure how to ask this question, but I'll try anyway. I found different people having some kind of similar problem. But none with the exact same issue.

I have a grails 2.3.x application, it uses a customized version of a plugin. I'm use to old versions of Grails (pre-Maven dependency resolution), when we were able to include the customized version of the plugin into the `/lib` folder. I'm doing the same thing, but I am not able to solve anything. :(

Is there a way to *tell* grails, that `lib` directory (or some other, into the project folder) have the plugin zip file on it as we were use to?

**UPDATE**

Just to clarify. I want the packaged plugin into the project directory, not the *source code*.

**UPDATE 2**

Try to add the packaged plugin into `plugins` folder inside project root without any luck. While `BuildConfig.groovy` have the dependency declared or not.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I have understood your question correctly. It seems you want to use a customized version of a plugin in your grails-app. You can do so by creating a "custom-plugins" folder in the root of the application and placing the custom version of the plugin inside this folder. Then in the BuildConfig we can specify the plugin location at the beginning of the file like this:
Assuming I have

> myGrailsApp/custom-plugins/custom-plugin-1

```
grails.plugin.location."custom-plugin-1"="custom-plugins/custom-plugin-1"
```

That is it.

Comment: Can I do this with the packaged version of the plugin? As a "zip" file? I do not want to leave the source code there (it is versioned somewhere else)

Comment: You may need to place the zip file in the lib directory of the project and then install it using the BuildConfig: eg., if the plugin is `your-plugin-1.0`, then in BuildConfig you can use something like this:`runtime :your-plugin:1.0`

Comment: I'm sorry, but that doesn't work either. Grails cannot find the plugin no matter what I do, it ends with ```Error Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Could not find artifact```

Answer (score 0):

If you package the plugin as a .zip file and put it in a `plugins` directory in the root of your application, it will be loaded from there. You might also need to remove the plugin dependency declaration from `BuildConfig.groovy` before this will work.

Comment: Strange, it does not do any good. I tried removing the ```BuildConfig.groovy``` and then, grails removed the plugin. If I include it, grails is not able to find it. Am I missing something?